# How can I get Octopus Deploy to redirect the error stream when installing a Windows Service?

Tags: c#, windows-services, console-application, octopus-deploy

I am currently using Octopus Deploy to deploy a Windows Service. Currently, it points to a console application and tries to use that as the Windows Service to install.

However, the call fails with the following error:

> Service cannot be started due to the following 
>   error: Cannot start service SomeService on computer '.'.

However, my console application should clearly redirect exceptions to the error log or at least show something in the standard out log, as shown in the source code below:

```
class Program
{
    private static void Main()
    {
        try
        {
            ...
            while (true)
            {
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("An error occured. It will be written to the error stream.");

            var errorMessage = ex.ToString();
            Console.Error.WriteLine(errorMessage.ToCharArray(), 0, errorMessage.Length);
            Console.Error.Flush();

            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you use to install a windows service, a built-in Octopus functionality?

Comment: Simple answer is that the code is never executed. The service cannot start due to a config or credentials problem. Are you able to check the event log?